# jQuery.ajax() - undefined data returned in IE9

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-9

i have a very simple code:

```
$.ajax({
  cache: false,
  dataType: 'html',
  complete: function(jqXHR){
    console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
  },
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
  },
  url: 'http://follows.pl/pages/ajaxtest'
});
```

it returns some text in ff, chrome and IE8, but in IE9 it shows twice "undefined".

I've looked into developer tool in IE9, and it showing a normal response so the request works fine, response is fine, but variables are undefined

headers of response:

```
Response    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control   no-cache
Content-Type    text/html; charset: UTF-8
Pragma  no-cache
```

response

```
string(4) "test"
```

Comment: [*Some types of Ajax requests, such as JSONP and cross-domain GET requests, do not use XHR; in those cases the XMLHttpRequest and textStatus parameters passed to the callback are undefined.*](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#callback-functions) I'd expect that to happen in all or older IE versions instead of newer ones though.

Answer (score 7):

I suspect this is your problem:

```
Content-Type    text/html; charset: UTF-8
```

That value is not correctly formatted (the ':' after charset is wrong) and IE9 doesn't like it, but silently fails instead of saying something useful. Try this:

```
Content-Type:    text/html;charset=utf-8
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried everything to solve this problem of ajax posting on IE browser (e.g. adding to the jquery ajax object no cache, dataType, configType, etc...), but at end the problem was not in ajax/javascript but in the PHP file: only **for IE browser the PHP file had to start with the following header**:

```
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

so, you have to **explicitly indicate the content type** of the php page that you get as result of your ajax call.

Example, assuming a html page called *one.html* where you place your javascript and a php page called *two.php*

In one.html set javascript as

```
var url = 'two.php';
$.ajax({
url: url,
type: "POST",
success: function(response){
alert(response)
}
});
```

In two.php page set as follows:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
echo ('stuff to do');
?>
```

in this way for me it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$.ajax({
  cache: false,
  dataType: 'html',
  complete: function(data){
    console.log(data);
  },
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
  },
  url: 'http://follows.pl/pages/ajaxtest'
});
```

## notice

in the success function

```
 success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR)
```

the object is the `third` argument.

you actually response from data by accessing a property which doesnt exists there.

also in the complete function

```
 complete: function (jqXHR, complete_textStatus)
```

here the object is `first` place !

you have to remember the locations .

Comment: the problem is that in success i should have any data, but i don't have it.